# For how long the Thread will live in a previous Activity

Tags: android

I'm wondering if I can rely on a task which is executing in a separate non UI thread if I'm leaving an `Activity`. Looking on example below I can see the `Runnable` in a separate `Thread` is executing even if I'm on another `Activity`. But when would it be killed?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        runTask();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
    }

    private void runTask() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    Log.i("Dev", "here I am");
                    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `java.lang.Thread` is not tied to the Android UI component lifecycle, so just like in a normal JVM it will keep going until its `run()` method returns... *unless* Android terminates your entire application process before that happens, which it can do if you app is in the background and another app needs the RAM.

Incidentally, because the thread is not tied to the UI component lifecycle, you cannot simply call into another UI component from that thread. You'll have to post to a `Handler` or issue a broadcast or something if you want to get back to the UI, but you may already know that.

Finally, in your sample code, the `Thread` instance (through the anonymous `Runnable`) will keep the enclosing Activity class from being garbage collected, so you may want to re-think that construct.

If you want to do background work that's not tied to any single `Activity`, you're generally better off modelling it as an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

Answer (score -1):

you can call `Interrupt()` that will post a interrupt request for your thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html